# Number of multiplications done in iterated squaring

Tags: python

The following code computes a**b using iterated squaring:

```
def power(a,b):
   result=1
   while b>0:
      if b % 2 == 1: 
         result = result*a 
      a = a*a  
      b = b//2
   return result
```

Suppose the decimal numbers `a` and `b` have `n` and `m` bits in their binary representation.

I'm trying to understand how many multiplications the code does for the smallest and biggest numbers `a` and `b` could be depending on `n` and `m`.

I know that in lines 5 and 6 of the code, a multiplication is done, but I'm struggling expressing the number of multiplications with the number of bits of `a` and `b` in their binary representation.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the number of multiplications depend only on one factor for this algorithm - which is `b` (`while b > 0`).

We meet operations that changes `b`'s value inside the loop once, where `b = b//2`.

While dealing with binary representation, dividing by two leads to the last bit being shifted right - and since we got `m` bits in `b`, that would mean the loop will be executed `m` times.

Since every time we have at least one multiplication and maximum two (depending on the number of `1`s in `m`), and m is guaranteed to be larger than 0 for the loop to occur, we get **a total of minimum `m+1` and maximum `m*2` multiplications**.

Comment: I'm not following. For example, for 2**6, the loop will go 3 times, so the code will do 2*3=6 multiplications, but the representation of 6 in binary is 3 bits long.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. What I explained is that the loop will repeat m times. It would commit multiplication once every time, and twice (one additional for the `result`) when the least significant bit is on (so between m and m*2 multiplications total).

Comment: Could you please give an example where there will be m multiplications?

Comment: @Itay4 correct, there won't, since m must be larger than 0 (and therefore at least one more bit is on)

Comment: One last question please: how can I generalize which of the cases, m+1 or 2m, will it be?

Comment: And for 2**5, I get 5 multiplications, and 5 has 3 bits in it's binary representation, which doesn't match neither m+1 nor 2m, what am I missing?

Comment: You can't generalize, because it is a range - `[m+1, 2m]`. If I have `100101`, it will commit `m=6` mandatory multiplications of `a = a*a`, plus `3` multiplications of `result = result*a`, as I have `3`  `1`s in my binary number (therefore, by dividing it by 2 every time it would end up odd `3` times [binary ending with `1` is odd]), so `9` total. `7 <= 9 <= 12`.

Comment: @Itay4 Is it a part of assignment? If so what was the exact question?

Comment: Oh, I see now, didn't realize it was range. Yes, it is an assignment. The question was about the same as I asked, and now I also need to show what should a and b in order to get the m+1 and 2m.

Comment: Well, it would be `m+1` only in the case of `b=1`, and `2m` whenever `b` is  `2**k-1` for every `k>=1`.

Comment: Notice that in the case of `b=1`, `m+1=2m`.

Comment: Oh, the -1 is not in the power?